# Java HashMap Get Values (the most of which value)

Tags: java, hashmap

Hi so a strange question...
Let's start with a simple description of the code:
I have a hashmap filled with `<PlayerUUID, KingdomUUID>`
Where the playerUUID is the key in the hashmap (obviously)

Now for my capture process system I need to determine how many of the diffrent values there is and thus which has the most.

For example:
3 players are attacking a point, 2 players are in ORION kingdom, 1 in Erion.
I need to check the values of the hashmap to see which of the kingdoms has the most attackers. (ORION is the answer)

Regards,
Thomas

I hope this description was good enough if not ask away!

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Make a new HashMap<KingdomUUID, Integer>, loop over all Map.Entry<PlayerUUID, KingdomUUID> in your map and do an auto increment on the one in the new hashmap. In the end, you can just loop over that hashmap and get the max.

Comment: I'm trying that atm but my brain is having a meltdown, I got the first 2 parts but in the end I just can't manager to get the highest value key from the new hashmap, I'm proberbly just being tired but I can't find the simple solution on how to find the highest value and thus get the key from that :S

Comment: (1) "let's start with a simple description of the code" -- why describe the code when you could just show us the map declaration? (2) The fantasy game stuff clouds your actual question; it would be easier to answer if you just used `key` and `value` and asked how to find the `value` that occurs the most times.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what f1sh did. However, Java 8 added streams and lambdas, which you can use as well. The resulting code is more compact, more readable, and less error prone. This code will be a bit slower, however you probably won't even feel it unless you deal with a lot of values.

```
public KingdomUUID getMax(HashMap<PlayerUUID, KingdomUUID> inputMap) {
    return inputMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max((entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() > entry2.getValue() ? 1 : -1)
        .get()
        .getValue();
}
```

More about [Java 8 streams.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

More about [Java 8 lambdas.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Comment: I want to have it said that PlayerUUID and KingdomUUID is actually not objects but the name of UUID objects :)

Would this stilll work the same?

Comment: @KingConquest You mean that those values are Strings? Sure it will. It will work with any type of keys and values. However, I'm not sure why you would save Strings and not actual objects into the Map?

Comment: *I need to check the values of the hashmap to see which of the kingdoms has the most attackers.* But this answer just returns the KingdomUUID with the highest value?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
Entry<KingdomUUID, Integer> getMax(Map<PlayerUUID, KingdomUUID> input) {
  Map<KingdomUUID, Integer> r = new HashMap<>();
  for(KingdomUUID kingdom:input.values()){
    final Integer old = r.get(kingdom);
    r.put(kingdom, old==null?1:old+1);
  }
  Map.Entry<KingdomUUID, Integer> max = null;
  for(Map.Entry<KingdomUUID, Integer> e:r.entrySet()){
    if(max==null || e.getValue()>max.getValue()){
      max = e;
    }
  }
  return max;
}
```

You can use `getKey()` on the return object to see which KingdomUUID occurs most often and and `getValue()` how many times.